# Check if all properties are false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React state is as follows :

```
[
   {type: "Benzine", active: false},
   {type: "Diesel", active: false},
   {type: "Electricity", active: false}
]
```

How can I check if all `active` values are false.

Is there any way to do it with lodash?

Comment: [`!arr.some(obj => obj.active !== false);`](https://jsfiddle.net/5vxbdcy6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to test wether every `active` property is true:

```js
    var arr = [
       {type: "Benzine", active: false},
       {type: "Diesel", active: false}, 
       {type: "Electricity", active: false}
    ]

    console.log(arr.every(obj => obj.active));
```

```js
var arr = [
       {type: "Benzine", active: true},
       {type: "Diesel", active: true}, 
       {type: "Electricity", active: true}
   ]

   console.log(arr.every(obj => obj.active));
```

```js
    var arr = [
       {type: "Benzine", active: false},
       {type: "Diesel", active: true}, 
       {type: "Electricity", active: false}
    ]

    console.log(arr.every(obj => obj.active));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the every function of loadash to check if active is false for every object.

```
var data = [
    {type: "Benzine", active: false},
    {type: "Diesel", active: false},
    {type: "Electricity", active: true}
];
// First argument is the data and second argument is the predicate to check
var res = _.every(data, {active: false}); // Returns true if all elements pass the predicate match else false.
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML  =  res;
```